# Minikube with Istio Gateway Connection Refused

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, istio

I'm trying to get a local kubernetes cluster running with Minikube and Istio. I followed the instructions found in the istio docs here: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/installing-istio.html

Then I followed the steps to install the sample BookInfo sample here: https://istio.io/docs/samples/bookinfo.html

However when I try and curl the Gateway URL, I get a connection refused error. All my pods and services appear to be running. Here is the result of the `kubectl get pods` command:

```
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
details-v1-1932527472-ggpf1      2/2       Running   0          8m
grafana-1261931457-d7wwx         1/1       Running   0          12m
istio-ca-3887035158-hnmkr        1/1       Running   0          12m
istio-egress-1920226302-vx1ml    1/1       Running   0          12m
istio-ingress-2112208289-kkblh   1/1       Running   0          12m
istio-manager-2910860705-qj8wv   2/2       Running   0          12m
istio-mixer-2335471611-hnnsz     1/1       Running   0          12m
productpage-v1-241699992-kl5mt   2/2       Running   0          8m
prometheus-3067433533-mdmp5      1/1       Running   0          12m
ratings-v1-2565146534-112g5      2/2       Running   0          8m
reviews-v1-2536835021-fp16t      2/2       Running   0          8m
reviews-v2-3299280847-x687f      2/2       Running   0          8m
reviews-v3-4061726673-6f4gb      2/2       Running   0          8m
servicegraph-3127588006-zc1w4    1/1       Running   0          12m
```

Here is the result of the `kubectl get services` command:

```
NAME            CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       
AGE
details         10.0.0.151   <none>        9080/TCP                      10m
grafana         10.0.0.243   <pending>     3000:32076/TCP                14m
istio-egress    10.0.0.22    <none>        80/TCP                        14m
istio-ingress   10.0.0.96    <pending>     80:31126/TCP,443:30916/TCP    14m
istio-manager   10.0.0.90    <none>        8080/TCP,8081/TCP             14m
istio-mixer     10.0.0.68    <none>        9091/TCP,9094/TCP,42422/TCP   14m
kubernetes      10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP                       14m
productpage     10.0.0.139   <none>        9080/TCP                      10m
prometheus      10.0.0.95    <pending>     9090:32474/TCP                14m
ratings         10.0.0.110   <none>        9080/TCP                      10m
reviews         10.0.0.197   <none>        9080/TCP                      10m
servicegraph    10.0.0.230   <pending>     8088:32648/TCP                14m
```

Then I run these commands:

```
export GATEWAY_URL=$(kubectl get po -l istio=ingress -o 'jsonpath={.items[0].status.hostIP}'):$(kubectl get svc istio-ingress -o 'jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].nodePort}')
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://${GATEWAY_URL}/productpage
```

The response I get is `000`. Hitting the endpoint with my browser gives me a connection refused error. I had this working at some point, and I have no idea where it broke down the line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Version Information

### Minikube

`minikube version: v0.19.0`

### Kubectl

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T20:41:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-09T23:22:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

### Istio

```
istioctl version:

Version: 0.1.5
GitRevision: 21f4cb4
GitBranch: master
User: jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-de3bbfab70500
GolangVersion: go1.8
KubeInjectHub: docker.io/istio
KubeInjectTag: 0.1


apiserver version:

Version: 0.1.5
GitRevision: 21f4cb4
GitBranch: master
User: jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-de3bbfab70500
GolangVersion: go1.8.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a support/troubleshooting question

Can you link this question in https://github.com/istio/issues/issues
and click "New Issue", link the great details you already did put here but also add the value of `GATEWAY_URL` and/or the full output of

```
curl -v http://${GATEWAY_URL}/productpage
```

there. thanks !

Also Minikube v0.19.0 has known issues, please upgrade to v0.19.1 and try again to see if this alone solves your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried updating to minikube v0.19.1, but the same problem occurs. I created a github issue here https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/25, and I'll mark this as answered.